# iptables block everything but http/https/ssh

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, firewall, fail2ban

I have this iptables configuration on my vps which is supposed to run Wordpress. What I want to do is block every incoming request except http on port 80, https on port 443 and ssh on port 22.

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
    num  target     prot opt source               destination         
    1    f2b-sshd   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports ssh
    
    Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
    num  target     prot opt source               destination         
    
    Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
    num  target     prot opt source               destination         
    
    Chain f2b-sshd (1 references)
    num  target     prot opt source               destination         
    1    REJECT     all  --  [retracted_ip]       anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    2    REJECT     all  --  [retracted].com     anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    3    RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

I have found some commands online, but what I'm not sure about is if they might conflict with fail2ban.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general:

Firewall rules get processed in the order they are set and appear (in the output of the `iptables -L -v -n  --line-numbers` , `iptables -L -v -n -t nat --line-numbers`,  `iptables-save` and/or similar commands).

Creating new rules in the wrong chains and/or the wrong order  will result in unwanted consequences, breaking functionality,  security and/or locking out valid traffic.

Be aware that running  low level `iptables` commands to manage your firewall may not always be the best solution. As far as I know in Ubuntu using the UFW tooling is preferred and will work reliably in concert with fail2ban.

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Firewall
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW

---

Fail2ban creates one or more custom chains (that handle most of the heavy lifting for blocking specific misbehaving IP-addresses) like the `f2b-sshd` chain. Normally you let fail2ban manage the entries in those chains.

Additionally fail2ban creates rules to the custom chains it creates in the `INPUT` chain.  Normally those rules must come *first in the* `INPUT` chain, before any other rules you create.

In your current firewall config when you use iptables with the `-A` switch to append new rules to the INPUT chain everything should work.

---

Running the following commands will append the usual rules to create a firewall that allows ssh, http and https, and which blocks all other incoming traffic.

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp  -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp  -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

Answer (score 0):

First let's backup :)

```
sudo iptables-save > ./mybackup
```

If you lost connect and want KVM you can easy back to your start of backup

```
sudo iptables-restore < ./mybackup
```

**Then you can start adding rules**

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -d YOURIPPUBLIC -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -d YOURIPPUBLIC  -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -d YOURIPPUBLIC  -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -d YOURIPPUBLIC  -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
sudo iptables -A INPUT -d YOURIPPUBLIC  -j DROP
```

this above if you want make firewall for ip another than your instance, YOURIPPUBLIC  : 33.33.33.33 or with netmask 33.33.33.33/32

RELATED,ESTABLISHED - If got before connect just skip all firewall next rules, To get connect this follow next rules :)

**if you want whole network**

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
sudo iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

You can save for later to edit:

```
iptables-save > /.mynew.iptables.list.txt
```